# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘g_get_os_info’

Tags: c, gtk

Cannot use `g_get_os_info` function in documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-os-info)

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

#define G_OS_INFO_KEY_PRETTY_NAME

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
 ...
 gchar *s = g_get_os_info(G_OS_INFO_KEY_PRETTY_NAME);
 printf("%s\n", s);

 gtk_main();
}
```

compilation error occurs

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘g_get_os_info’
```

compile in this way `` gcc main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` && ./a.out ``

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That function was added in version 2.64, which was originally released at the end of February. Are you compiling with at least version 2.64.0 of the library?

Comment: These are not errors, but warnings. Anyway, whenever you see those two warnings, consider them always as errors.